# Unspecified size of array in function parameter

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I can't able to understand , so please help me .
Whrn we are passing the array to any function and then we write the array type in function parameter to fetch it but why we are not initialize its size in the parameter .

Comment: If I understand your question: you can't pass C-style arrays by value. They're passed by address always. Even if you put a size in the parameter it'll really be replaced by a pointer to the element type.

Comment: "Whrn we are passing the array to any function..." - what do you mean by that? Passing **how**? Make an example. An actual piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you could specify (fixed) size of array as function parameter - you have to pass array by reference.

```
void func(int (&x)[100]);
```

is passing array of int with size 100.

You could even make a template for it

```
template<class T, size_t N> void func(T (&x)[N]) {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

**In C++, always prefer containers to raw pointers or arrays when possible.**

Array types in function signatures are actually pointers.  The following three declarations are all exactly the same:

```
void foo(int a[10]);
void foo(int a[]);
void foo(int* a);
```

In all three cases, `foo` takes a single parameter: a pointer to an `int`.  When you pass an array to that function, it implicitly decays to a pointer to its first element.

When an array decays into a pointer, the length of the array is lost.  That means the following code will compile, but is logically wrong:

```
void foo(int a[10]) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        std::cout << a[i] << '\n';
    }
}

int main() {
    // Whoops, wrong size array!
    int arr[5] = {};
    foo(arr);
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/212add0591cff556)

The length declaration, in this case, is a complete and total lie.  Writing a meaningless number in the function definition just increases the risk someone will make an error.

---

If you must use raw pointers for a function parameter accepting an array, your function should also accept a size parameter:

```
void foo(int* a, size_t length) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        std::cout << a[i] << '\n';
    }
}

int main() {
    int arr[5] = {};
    foo(arr, 5);
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e69eb49e1a5e6dbd)

This is also dangerous though, since it's entirely possible for someone to pass the *wrong* size and cause errors:

```
void foo(int* a, size_t length) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        std::cout << a[i] << '\n';
    }
}

int main() {
    int arr[5] = {};
    //Whoops, passed the wrong size!
    foo(arr, 10);
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/70ebc288aa239325)

For that reason, you should prefer to use a container:

```
void foo(const std::vector<int>& a) {
    for (int i : a) {
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> arr(5);
    foo(arr);
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fb10932da8c3996c)

If you don't know what type of container to use; default to `std::vector`.  If your function must support multiple types of containers, use a template:

```
template <typename Container>
void foo(const Container& a) {
    for (int i : a) {
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> arr(5);
    foo(arr);
    std::array<int, 5> arr2 = {};
    foo(arr2);
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e99c459ecf1f924f)

Comment: `Array types in function signatures are actually pointers` only if passed by value.